# Adding animation to google vizualisations (Column Chart)?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, google-visualization

I wanted to know if there are any resources on how I can make my google graphs look a little more sleek via CSS3 animations.

I've been looking through some CSS3 animations (http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/index.html) and would like to implement the "pullUp" animation on the columns of my google chart. I understand that I need to add the 'pullUp' class to each column; however, because the column is created dynamically via Javascript, I'm not sure the best way to make that happen.

Can anyone provide some pointers, or help? Attached is the codepen with my existing code: [CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CbelI)

Any help is extremely appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The charts support animations out-of-the-box: they animate when you change the data, so you can draw the chart with an empty data set and then redraw it with your full data set and it will animate:

```
function drawVisualization() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Tracker', '1', '2', '3'],
        ['A', 475, 450, 190],
        ['B', 300, 290, 20],
        ['C', 360, 340, 120],
        ['D', 180, 170, 250]
    ]);

    // use a DataView to 0-out all the values in the data set for the initial draw
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, {
        type: 'number',
        label: data.getColumnLabel(1),
        calc: function () {return 0;}
    }, {
        type: 'number',
        label: data.getColumnLabel(2),
        calc: function () {return 0;}
    }, {
        type: 'number',
        label: data.getColumnLabel(3),
        calc: function () {return 0;}
    }]);

    // Create and draw the visualization.


    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));

    var options = {
        title:"Sub-Region vs Region vs Budget",
        legend: 'bottom',
        hAxis: {
            title: ""
        },
        animation: {
            duration: 1000
        },
        vAxis: {
            // set these values to make the initial animation smoother
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 600
        }
    };

    var runOnce = google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        google.visualization.events.removeListener(runOnce);
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });

    chart.draw(view, options);

    // you can handle the resizing here - no need to recreate your data and charts from scratch
    $(window).resize(function() {
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/bwULk/

Answer (score 2):

**Updated answer**

Animation on startup is out of the box with the "startup : true" option.
Changing values is no longer needed

```
function drawVisualization() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Tracker', '1', '2', '3'],
        ['A', 475, 450, 190],
        ['B', 300, 290, 20],
        ['C', 360, 340, 120],
        ['D', 180, 170, 250]
    ]);   

    // Create and draw the visualization.
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));

    var options = {
        title:"Sub-Region vs Region vs Budget",
        legend: 'bottom',
        hAxis: {
            title: ""
        },
        animation: {
            startup: true,
            duration: 1000
        },
        vAxis: {
            // set these values to make the initial animation smoother
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 600
        }
    };    

    chart.draw(data, options);

$(window).resize(function() {
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });
}
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bwULk/132/